# mariaex lib does not handle utf8 local language correctly [elixir]

Tags: elixir

I use `Mariaex` lib to connect to mysql in an `elixir` project. But it does not handle local language correctly.

For example,
When it save local text `Dương Phi Phụng` to mysql database, `D??ng Phi Ph?ng` was save in the db.

The default charset for `Mariaex` is `utf8`, but even when I set `charset: "utf8"` OR `charset: "utf8mb4"` in the config, it still did not work.

Can anyone help?

Mariaex version: `0.8.4` (cannot update to lastest version due to legacy issue)

db charset: `utf8mb4`

db collation: `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: in such cases you should open an issue on the github page

Comment: I recommend you hack open Mariaex, stick in a few `IO.inspect` lines and see what's happening. Alternatively, the ecto/postgres is a very well tested route for db in elixir.

Comment: Rather unbelievably, there's a question that looks like a similar issue, but relating to ecto/postgres: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61946283/how-do-i-avoid-ecto-matching-incorrectly-when-comparing-binary-ids-with-in-a

Comment: @cjm2671 I use `ecto prostgres` my main `postgres` database, but I use to connect a legacy `mysql` db. I do not have any issue with `ecto`.

Comment: Can you verify that you are able to do a raw MySQL INSERT statement using the utf8 encoded text?  I don't know if it applies to you, but I remember having encoding issues once with a MySQL database and the db charset/collation were correct, but I had to adjust the encodings for specific tables and columns (?) -- I don't remember now if that was a bug, but it might be worth verifying.

Comment: @Everett I tried raw INSERT statement, it did not work. ex. `INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('Dương Phi Phụng')`. Can you give me more details & example on how you adjust the encodings?

Comment: That's progress! You've verified that this is a database issue (and not a language issue).  I think this answer may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8
In my experience, the encoding defined at the db level didn't always get inherited by individual tables or columns, so you may need to modify the tables, e.g. `ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;` (or use the `utf8mb4` encoding if available).

Comment: I'm pretty sure for MySQL you always want `utf8mb4` and never `utf8`

Comment: @Everett the `charcter_set_name` for the `col` is `utf8mb4`. The issue might not be database as it is correctly inserted when I use  `myxql`. I think I should move to `ecto` with `Ecto.Adapters.MyXQL`.